# How do we connect MySql database in SpringBoot?

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I am beginner for Spring Boot and I want to connect to a MySQL database(8.0.15) but when I run my application I am getting the below exception and I am not able to understand it. How can I resolve this problem?

> java.sql.SQLException: The connection property 'zeroDateTimeBehavior'
> only accepts values of the form: 'exception', 'round' or
> 'convertToNull'. The value 'CONVERT_TO_NULL' is not in this set.

### application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL&serverTimezone=GMT
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
```

Comment: Just check your error message that you should be using `convertToNull` instead of `CONVERT_TO_NULL`.

Comment: now i am getting com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.

Comment: Can you connect to MySQL from Workbench?  Also, maybe try pinging that host to see if be reachable from your computer.

Comment: yes i connect to mysql workbench

Answer (score 0):

Change your connection string to `zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull` instead of `zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL`

Comment: Ok @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: No he probably meant I could've put it as comment instead of answering, nothing you did wrong

Comment: now i am getting com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.

Comment: This problem occurs when the MySQL service is not running and you're trying to connect to the mysql database or when the connection is not reachable for some reason. Make sure MySQL service is running and validate your connection

Comment: MySQL service  is running

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 - Add dependency for your database connector to pom.xml
Example for MySQL is shown below.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

If you would want to connect to oracle database, you can use a dependency similar to the one shown below.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
    <version>12.1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Step 2 - Remove H2 Dependency from pom.xml
Or at least make its scope as test

```
<!--
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
-->
```

Step 3 - Setup your My SQL Database
We would need to set up your database with a schema and the tables.

```
For an example, check out - https://github.com/in28minutes/jpa-with-hibernate#installing-and-setting-up-mysql
```

Step 4 - Configure your connection to Your Database
Configure application.properties to connect to your database.

An example for My SQL is shown below:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/todo_example
spring.datasource.username=todouser
spring.datasource.password=YOUR_PASSWORD
```

> spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto

Spring Boot chooses a default value for this based on whether you are connecting to an embedded database or not.

```
Embedded Databases - default create-drop
Other Databases - default none
```

Here is a quick guide to all the options

```
none : No action will be performed.
create-only : Database creation will be generated from entities.
drop : Database dropping will be generated from entities.
create : Database dropping will be generated followed by database creation.
validate : Validate entites with the database schema
update: Update the database schema based on the entities
```

Step 5 - Restart and You are ready!
That’s it